# Cannot see dynamic view of COM Objects in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, com, c++-cli, visual-studio-debugging

I only recently switched to VS 2010 and learned about the dynamic view for examining objects of type System::__COMObject. I have a .NET project where I use a number of COM Objects, however when I add a watch to those objects I do not see any reference to the dynamic view.

I have included an image showing a partial breakdown of the watch window for one of these objects below[image: Watch output for spectrum object]

I simply added a watch to the spectrum2 object. Is it possible to get a dynamic view of these __COMObjects? Or am I completely misunderstanding how dynamic view should work?